# Custom wordpress vertical accordion menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, accordion

I have a wordpress site which I am trying to create a custom menu.  What I need it to do is if it has a child "ul" then treat the parent as the "accordion header" currently it works but up to 2 levels, if there is more than 2 then it hides the rest. Any help?

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-interno" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-629" class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-635" class=""><a href="http://#">Mujeres</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-636" class=""><a href="#">Xiomi</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-637" class="">
        <a href="#">Xiomi &#8211; Pink Candy</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-638">
            <a href="#">Xiomi &#8211; Electric City</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-639">
        <a href="#">Xiomi &#8211; Cupcake Girl</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu-interno{
float: left;
width: 280px;
/*border-top: 1px solid #999;
border-right: 1px solid #999;
border-left: 1px solid #999;*/
}
#menu-interno li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000 !important;
}
#menu-interno li ul {
  display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
  margin: 4px 0 15px;
}
#menu-interno li ul li a {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#menu-interno > li > a').click(function(){
     if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
       $('#menu-interno li ul').slideUp();
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
       $('#menu-interno li a').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ul li as selector, use different classes.

Comment: Im sorry can u elaborate a lil? Not asking for the whole solution just a clue as to how to change it? css or js, and change it for what? Thanks :)

Comment: '#menu-interno li ul' will select all uls in first li, so use different classes can directly select any ul or li you want.